# Dynamic enum values on nested classes with Python

Tags: python, enums

Consider the following `enum` class:

```py
from enum import Enum


class Namespace:

    class StockAPI(Enum):
        ITEMS = "{url}/items"
        INVENTORY = "{url}/inventory"

    class CustomerAPI(Enum):
        USERS = "{url}/users"
        PURCHASES = "{url}/purchases"

    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
```

I am trying to make `url` a dynamic value for each `enum` class.

What can I do here so that I can call some `enum` class in one of the following ways:

- `Namespace.StockAPI.ITEMS.value` would return `http://localhost/items`?
- `Namespace(url="http://localhost").StockAPI.ITEMS.value` would also return `http://localhost/items`

Is this possible to do without doing variable interpolation each time I access each `enum` property? Could `factory` pattern be of any help here?

Comment: Is your question how you can insert a variable in a string, or was there some particular problem specifically related to creating an `Enum` class?

Comment: @mkrieger1 it's more of a design issue, so it's coser to your second option: how to create a some ```Enum``` class considering a dynamic value like ```url```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did it the following way, while keeping the inner `enum` classes:

```py
from enum import Enum


class Namespace:

    class StockAPI(Enum):
        ITEMS = "{url}/items"
        INVENTORY = "{url}/inventory"

    class CustomerAPI(Enum):
        USERS = "{url}/users"
        PURCHASES = "{url}/purchases"

    def __init__(self, url: str):
        attrs = (getattr(self, attr) for attr in dir(self))
        enums = (a for a in attrs if isinstance(a, type) and issubclass(a, Enum))
        for enum in enums:
            kv = {e.name: e.value.format(url=url) for e in enum}
            setattr(self, enum.__name__, Enum(enum.__name__, kv))

print(Namespace(url="http://test.com").StockAPI.ITEMS.value)
# http://test.com/items
```

Comment: Other than those minor issues, it's a clever solution: recreating the `Enum`s when you instantiate a `Namespace`.

Comment: @EthanFurman indeed , I was missing the ```Enum``` import

Answer (score 1):

use f-string:

```
ITEMS = "{}/items".format(url)
```

and so on,
but if you use classes, then add new attribute and call it in f-string:

```
class MyClass:
   url = "htpp://www.some.thing"

obj = MyClass()
ITEMS = "{0.url}/items".format(obj)
```

if you don't have same names, it is possible to implement it without any Enum:

```
class Namespace:
    def __init__(self, url): 
        USERS = "{}/users".format(url)
        PURCHASES = "{}/purchases".format(url)
        ITEMS = "{}/items".format(url)
        INVENTORY = "{}/purchases".format(url)

obj = Namespace("https://www.some.news")
print(obj.USERS)        # https://www.some.news/users
print(obj.PURCHASES)    # https://www.some.news/purchases
print(obj.ITEMS)        # https://www.some.news/items    
print(obj.INVENTORY)    # https://www.some.news/inventory
```